# Script that changes commands as per the environment

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

```
while read -r -u10 server port line
do
  echo server: "$server" port: "$port"
  ssh -qn "$server" "netstat -tulpun | grep -E \"\b$port\b\""
  echo
done 10< demo
```

This script will give you the output mentioned below, can I do `ps -ef | grep 1505` to the ID which is in the output

```
server: Jan  port: 8000  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1505/httpd  

server: feb  port: 8000  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1505/httpd
```

Comment: You should keep both expecting and actual output together to understand the difference or error in existing code.

Comment: `but having some issue` - what's the issue? What output are you expecting?

Comment: all the output prints together with out any gape between 2 commands & some time some host doesn't give output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your issue is but you can probably improve your code a bit:

```
while read -r server port line
do  
  echo server: "$server" port: "$port"  
  ssh -qn "$server" "netstat -ntl | grep -E \"\b$port\b\""
  echo
done < demo
```

Comment: I just want to run netstat command on all the server mentioned in the fire with the port, there are 2 column. ssh to the server & run netstat command with port mentioned for the related server

Comment: The code above will do this... And yes I did, it's on the final line.

Comment: the above script just  give the first host output

Comment: the ssh line is not printing, i dont know what the reason

Comment: see the update, ssh reads stdin so need to use a different file descriptor